# What is $N$ such that the $S$ set becomes non-coupled?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The question is : for integers $a,b,c,N$ with $N>0$, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - Nabc = 2022$.
Find the $N$ where integer solutions of the equation exists.

I think we should make a secondary surplus using a modular. In addition, if one magnetic root exists, the solution will be infinite. Through the relationship between root and coefficient. I'd appreciate it if you answer me!

+
if N==1 or 2(mod 3), Because 2022==3(mod 9), solution doesn't exists.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it's not one.

Comment: Have you tried some obvious solutions? For example, take $a=b=1$. Then we have $c(c-N)=2020=20\cdot 101$, so $c=101$ gives a solution with $N=81$. You can obtain many $N$ by this way.

Comment: Oh, it's gotten a lot easier to determine if a solution exists for a given N. Then is there any other way to find all N's?

Comment: Yes, but start trying first something yourself.

Comment: See what you can make of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+++++a%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+c%5E2+-+N+%28a+b+c%29+%3D+2022%2C+N%3E1++over+integers) from WolframAlpha